# Drag to move tablayout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I want my tab layout to move from right to left and left to right on drag. I am not talking about scrolling, I mean drag to move the whole view.

I already have tabs setup, I just want to know a way to drag and move the tablayout in and out of the screen keeping only 1 element on the screen. 
Here is what i  want to achieve

Screen 1:

[image]

Screen 2:

[image]

Comment: So, you want, when a user selects any tab, and then scroll the content above, it should become like screen 1. Right ?

Comment: No, I want user to drag the tablayout to the left to show the remaining tabs which are off screen, as by default  i will be showing only the 1st tab.

Comment: Okay got you. What ux you want when a user clicks 'Internal Events'? So, in that case, screen1 (Instead of All events, Internal Events to be shown) or it will show like screen2?

Comment: @ANANDSONI i just want my tabbarlayout which has all the tabs to scroll horizontally, on user drag and by default i want to show only All events tab on the right edge of the screen. If the user click and drags the All events tab to the left of the screen then all other tabs will start to show up to the user and vise-versa

Comment: Got you. I hope I come with a solution for you.